# How can I pass data like list group from one html page to another using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newCategory.js"></script>


    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category name" id="categoryName">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="card" id="cardId">
        <div class="card-block">

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter item" id="name1">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number"  onclick="addRow(1)" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            </span>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-group" id="mylistgroup1">
                <li id="li1" class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            </ul>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveCategory()">save category</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my second HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/edit.js"></script>
    <h3>Minimum 2 categories and minimum 20 items in order to publish the game <span class="label label-default"></span></h3>

    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter game's name"  name="fname" id="fname">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addNewCategory()">Add category</button>

    <br class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block" id="card1">
                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeCategory(1)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                        <h4 class="card-title">Friends</h4>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter item" id="name1">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number"  onclick="addRow(1)" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="list-group" id="mylistgroup1" >
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"">Cras justo odio</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vestibulum at eros</button>
                        </ul>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteRow(1)">delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block" id="card2">

                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeCategory(2)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Seinfeld</h4>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter item" id="name2">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" onclick="addRow(2)" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="list-group" id="mylistgroup2">
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Cras justo odio</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</button>
                            <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Vestibulum at eros</button>
                        </ul>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteRow(2)">delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card content-->
                </div>
                <!--/.Card-->
            </div>

        </div> <!-- row -->
    <div><br> <br> </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveGame()">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="back()">back</button>
    </div> <!-- container -->
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When SaveCategory button is clicked, the category name and the listgroup should be sent and displayed in the second html page. 
Please suggest me what code I should use for this.

Comment: Second html page ? please explain

Comment: I mean the bottom page

Comment: Sent it in the URL as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need server side coding to send data from one page to another page

Comment: or you can use local/session storage in one page and retrieve data in another

Comment: Can you give me an example of sending a simple value?

Comment: How can I store list group values in local storage?

Comment: localStorage.setItem("lastname", [1,2,3]);

Comment: I tried to do this:                                                                            
 function saveCategory() {
    var getInput=document.getElementById("categoryName").value;
    var list=document.getElementById("mylistgroup1").value;
    localStorage.setItem("storageName",getInput);
    localStorage.setItem("listgroup",list);

    window.location.href = "Edit.html";
}                                                                                                                       but the values of mylistgroup1 are not shown

Comment: before saving in local storage serialize your list and save it and while retrieving deserialize it

Comment: use JSON.stringify(list) and JSON.parse(localstorage value);

Comment: I got an error:                        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at saveGame (edit.js:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Edit.html:94)

Comment: localStorage.setItem("listgroup",JSON.stringify(list));

Comment: window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse("listgroup")));

Comment: no no not like that use window.onload = alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listgroup")));

Comment: I am still getting this error:Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: give me your output of localStorage.getItem("listgroup")

Comment: the output is: undefined

Comment: i think your list is empty give me your output of JSON.stringify(list)

Comment: The output is:undefined

Comment: But as you can see the list is not empty: <ul class="list-group" id="mylistgroup1">
                <li id="li1" class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            </ul>

Comment: thats not how you take value from html list you need to iterate through childrens of ul ie all <li> tags and add their value in list

Comment: refer : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/715599/read-value-in-tag-li-and-save-in-array-with-Javasc

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is run in the client browser, so for these purposes is more suitable to use server-side technology, for example PHP, but anyway you can do this via JavaScript too with LocalStorage.
You can save the data at the one page and then request it on another page with this code:

```
localStorage.setItem('your_variable', 'test'); //save
localStorage.getItem('your_variable') //request
```

Comment: How can I send the values of mylistgroup1 between the pages using LocalStorage?